# XPath Extractor - SAXParseException - Xpath Query

Tags: xpath, jmeter

I need to extract the value 53177610 associated with serviceUsername from the Response Data and used XPATH Extractor as indicated below

### Response Data

```
<input type="hidden" name="serviceUsername"

         value="53177610"> <input type="hidden"
```

### XPATH Extractor

Reference Name:xpathserusername1

XPATH Query://input[@type="hidden"][@name="serviceUsername"]/@value

Default Value:Not Found

I get the following error SAXParseException. 
Assertion error: false
Assertion failure: true
Assertion failure message: The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".
See log file for further details.

Is there any error in the Xpath Query that can be picked up

Comment: Can you post a larger snippet of xml so we can check your xpath against the document structure

Comment: Sounds like your input is HTML and likely not valid XML.

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? if ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that users know it is usable. Thx

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your response is not XML/XHTML-compliant. JMeter can still deal with it, but you will need to tick `Use Tidy (tolerant parser)` box in the XPath Extractor

[image: Use Tidy XPath Extractor]

Given this box checked JMeter will use [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) library to "normalize" invalid XML or HTML so your XPath query should succeed.

You can test your XPath Expressions using "XPath Tester" mode of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

[image: XPath Tester]

See [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guide for more information on performing correlation using XPath queries

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your query, the problem is that your input isn't well-formed XML. Perhaps it is HTML.

Answer (score 0):

For HTML the best extractor is [CSS/JQuery](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) in JMeter. 
XPath Extractor is for XML not HTML. Tidying has a big cost and XPath library doesn't perform as well as CSS/JQuery.
Finally it is a much more maintainable and easy method, see below.

CSS/JQuery Expression will be:

> input[name=serviceUsername]

And Attribute:

> value

Which gives you:

[image]